# Libjpeg для Windows(Boost Gil)

Tags: c++, boost, jpeg

Работаю с Boost Gil. Нужно обрабатывать jpg изображения. Gil требует для работы libjpeg. Скачал libjpeg c http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm, подключил к проекту. Появились ошибки вроде

> G:\Libraries\jpeglib\include\unistd.h:54: ошибка: sys/times.h: No such file or directory

Далее скачал LibGW32C отсюда http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm, все скопировал в папку jpeglib\include и появились новые ошибки которые я не знаю как исправить, а именно

> G:\QT\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\cwchar:146: ошибка: '::fwide' has not been declared

Прочитал много статей и часто встречал вышеприведенный сайт в качестве источника libjpeg. Помогите разобраться с подключением libjpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Скачал пакет libjpeg-turbo используя утилиту vcpkg и все заработало.
Сколько не пытался бы скомпилировать из исходников в mingw-make и cmake не помогало. Vcpkg быстро помог.